# How to find few similar vectors in a huge amount of vectors?

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis, data-mining, hierarchical-clustering

Assume a huge amount (e.g. a billion) of vectors (e.g. stored in a database). All the vector have the same number of numerical values (e.g. each vector has 100,000 integer values). There is a distance function that tells the distance between two of the vectors (may be simple euclidan, or something more specific). Most of the vectors are very distant, but it might be that there are a few groups (e.g. around 1,000 vectors each, but each group with different size) that are very close to each other or even similar. Which algorithm can be used to find the those groups efficiently?

Hierarchical clustering (agglomerative) should be able to find all cluster in such a dataset. But I'm not interested in the whole set of clusters. Is there any way to limit the search or using a different algorithm?

Comment: Can you quantify the "*very close to each other*"? If so, then you can put to vectors in a cluster if their distance is smaller than some radius. Use a [union-find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to speed this up.

Comment: I can quantify the closeness by the maximum number of vector elements that deviate. If the data is perfect the vectors of the groups will be (nearly) identical, i.e. in an element-wise comparison (nearly) all elements of the vectors are identicial (distance will be around zero). Vectors that are not in the same group will have many deviations (and a much higher distance). I could write a distance function that intentionally returns a distance higher then a preconfigured threshold if more than 5% of the elements are different.